# Return Array After For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, for-loop

Having a hard time understanding for loops in arrays. Trying to create a Thank You card creator and these are the steps I'm trying to follow:

1. Create a new, empty array to hold the messages
2. Iterate through the input array and inside the loop build out the 'thank you' message for each name using string interpolation, then add that message to the new array you created
3. After the loop finishes and all of the messages have been added to the new array, return the new array.

```html
 const names = []
function writeCards(names, event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    console.log(`Thank you, ${names[i]} for the wonderful ${event} gift!`);
  return names;
}
```

Not sure if I'm on the right track. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is probably confusing (you) to have a global variable (const) `names` that is **shadowed** by the local `names` parameter. Use different names to help reduce the risk of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.push()`

```
function writeCards(names, event) {
  let messages = []
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
    messages.push("Thank you, " + names[i] + " for the wonderful " + event + " gift!")
  }
  return messages;
}
```

Comment: You're mixing up your standard string concatenation with template strings which is why the output looks weird.

Comment: @Andy Output should look fine as long as `names` is an array of strings and `event` is a string

Comment: If you do [some testing](https://jsfiddle.net/dw2qxa1L/) you'd see that isn't the case.

Comment: I see I made a typo it should work now, thank you @Andy

Answer (score 2):

I know your question is focused on `for` loop, but just in case, you might be interested in using `map` to achieve the desired result in a more concise manner:

```js
const names = ["Joe", "Nina"]

function writeCards(names, event) {
   return  names.map(name=> `Thank you, ${name} for the wonderful ${event} gift!`)
}

console.log(writeCards(names, "birthday"))
```

Answer (score 1):

well the i had this issue

i had an empty array outside a loop and wanted to update it inside a loop

and finally return an array with alot of indexes

```
    //ie 
    //let arr = [] 
    //LOOP then runs
    //then console.log(arr) //console shows [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

> this is how you do it

```
    let arr = []
    let realArray = [1,2,3,4,5] 
    for (let index = 0; index < realArray.length; index++) { 
       const element = realArray[index] 
       arr.push(element)
    }

    console.log(arr)//your arr = 1,2,3,4,5
```

this is my first answer here

Answer (score 0):

```js
function writeCards(names, event) {

 // 1) Create a new, empty array to hold the messages.

 // So, this should be done within the function. We want to be
 // able to update this locally-scoped array with the information
 // we get from each name in the array, combined with the event
 const messages = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

    // 2) using string interpolation

    // What's great is that you've already discovered template strings
    // String concatenation has its uses but this far better.
    const message = `Thank you, ${names[i]}, for the wonderful ${event} gift!`;

    // So, instead of logging the message to the console
    // we're going to push it to the messages array
    messages.push(message);
  }

  // 3) After the loop finishes and all of the messages
  // have been added to the new array, return the new array.
  return messages;

}

console.log(writeCards(['Bob', 'Sue'], 'wedding'));
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rather suggest to go with **@DoneDeal0** answer's.

In case, if you would like to go with for loop, there's one more cleaner way to go with it. You can use `forEach()` function given by javascript, as it takes two parameters in it, first is the value of each index and second is the index number itself.
Note: `forEach()` is just similar to `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`.

```
names = ["Robert", "King", "Joey"];

function writeCards(names) {
  let messages = [];
  names.forEach((name, index) => {
    messages.push("Thank you, " + name + " at " + index + " for the wonderful gift");
  });
  return messages;
}

console.log(writeCards(names));
```

Comment: Why is `forEach` cleaner?

Comment: You can have a look at this article -> https://alligator.io/js/foreach-vs-for-loops/. It will clear your doubt

Comment: Your answer makes the claim that it's "cleaner". You don't explain why. Nor do you explain why `for...of` is not even better than either.

Comment: I mean cleaner in terms of reading and understanding. Suppose if the above example would consist of three nested ```for``` loops, then what would you have said? (i.e. i, j, k) I don't think cleaner always means Time complexity & Space complexity

Comment: You're declaring an index in your answer but never using it. That's not cleaner. @AshwiniKumar

Comment: foreach does not take 2 parameters, also the article you mention does not state that foreach is cleaner.

Comment: You could run the program and see. I would also suggest to go through this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach and you can read in detail regarding this

Comment: Your code doesn't include the event @AshwiniKumar. What happened to that?

Comment: Ok it may can take 2 arguments but not value and index as you describe.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze the callback for `forEach` accepts an element and an index.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze forEach actually takes 3 parameters. The item on which you loop, its index, and the reference to the original array.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 Absolutely right. The third parameter is actually you can say the complete array itself. So it will give you output as ```Robert,King,Joey```

Comment: The callback takes 3 arguments, not foreach itself. foreach takes 2 arguments.

Comment: @Andy thats my point? So does foreach take value and index as arguments?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @Andy yes i did, did you read it?